# Баг в приложении

Tags: xcode, appstore

Здравствуйте.

Отправил в AppStore приложение на рассмотрение, и сразу после этого 
наткнулся на баг. Как в данном случае лучше всего поступить?
Удалить приложение и залить по новой или подождать ответа?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Я в таком же случае исправил баг и как только статус приложения изменился на "ready for sale" запустил обновление на рассмотрение. Все равно первую неделю приложение не будет индексировано в поиске по аппстору и его никто не найдет просто так. Если же это коммерческая и заранее широко разрекламированная программа то лучше отмените. Этот вариант не советовал сразу потому что при отмене можете столкнуться с неверным статусом выставленным Вашей программе (тоже известны случаи).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но ведь с багом можно и не дождаться статуса "ready for sale", просто откажут, и все?

Comment: могут и не отказать если баг не найдут, а если найдут и откажут - тоже ничего страшного. Свежий случай у нас на проекте дважды отказали из-за бага (в первый раз отвалился файлик html-подсказка в этапах сборки, второй раз случайно ту же багованую сборку отправили) - и ничего, на третий раз пропустили причем так быстро что мы сами в шоке были. Может конечно менеджер им там отписал что мы дико извеняемся, но послали не ту сборку, но факт остается фактом

Comment: В любом случае - большое спасибо:)